# How Kafka Connectors are reliable in case of failures?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm thinking of using a Kafka Connector vs creating my own Kafka Consumers/Producers to move some data from/to Kafka, and I see the value Kafka Connectors provide in terms of scalability and fault tolerance. However, I haven't been able to find how exactly connectors behave if the "Task" fails for some reason. Here are a couple of scenarios:

1. For a sink connector (S3-Sink), if it (the Task) fails (after all retries) to successfully send the data to the destination (for example due to a network issue), what happens to the worker? Does it crash? Is it able to re-consume the same data from Kafak later on?
2. For a source connector (JDBC Source), if it fails to send to Kafka, does it re-process the same data later on? Does it depend on what the source is?

Does answer to the above questions depend on which connector we are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

In Kafka 2.0, I think, they introduced the concept of graceful error handling, which can skip the over bad messages or write to a DLQ topic.

1) The S3 sink can fail, and it'll just stop processing data. However, if you fix the problem (for various edge cases that may arise) the sink itself is exactly once delivery to S3. The consumed offsets are stored as a regular consumer offset offset will not commit to Kafka until the file upload completes. However, obviously if you don't fix the issue before the retention period of a topic, you're losing data.

2) Yes, it depends on the source. I don't know the semantics of the JDBC Connector, but it really depends which query mode you're using. For example, for the incrementing timestamp, if you try to run a query every 5 seconds for all rows within a range, I do not believe it'll retry old, missed time windows

Overall, the failure recovery scenario are all dependent on the systems that are being connected to. Some errors are recoverable, and some are not (for example, your S3 access keys get revoked, and it won't write files until you get a new credential set)

Comment: Thanks. My main concern is data loss in case of errors on edge cases. If S3 Sink always commits its offset after successful upload to S3, is good enough for me. Generally speaking I'd like to make sure all data is successfully transferred to/from kafka if the error is transient and is fixed in a reasonable timeframe.